# How to enter Socks5 proxy in OpenVPN connect?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, openvpn, socks5

Looking for a way to add socks5 proxy settings to OpenVPN connect client.
the GUI only supports adding IP address and it uses HTTP.

[image]

I tried adding

```
socks-proxy 127.0.0.1 1008
```

to the config file but the client ignored that setting completely and connects without proxy.